# Indexing matrix elements when input arrays are equal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix and I want to be able to change the value of certain elements when indexing them with two array without using loops

For example

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0]])
b = np.array([0, 1, 2])
c = np.array([2, 3, 1, 1])
```

If an index i in b is equal to an index j in c then then access A[i,j]

I've tried

```
A[b, c] = 1
```

and

```
A[b == c] = 1
```

but I'm not getting the correct result
I believe the result should be

```
A = array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1, 1],
           [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: You mean `np.array` not just `array` .. right?

Comment: Yeah sorry. I'm using numpy

Comment: You need to iterate over `b` and `c` to see which indices are equal... I believe it's the most straight-forward way??

Comment: I should have specified but I'm specifically looking for a way to do it without any loops

Comment: Without loops and are of different shapes, this should be interesting.

Comment: It doesn't look like your expected output is right. For example, the first 1 should be at [0, 2]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.meshgrid` to expand your 1D indexing arrays to 2D indexing arrays:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0]])
b = np.array([0, 1, 2])
c = np.array([2, 3, 1, 1])

C,B = np.meshgrid(c,b)
A[B==C] = 1

print(A)
```

gives

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0]]
```